# understand Thread scheduling pattern

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I am using Eclipse IDE.

I asked this Question
[Multithread output not expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344329/multithread-output-not-expected)

The Question seemed stupid to some but still i got some valuable opinions .
In short I understood **threading is unpredictable**. Well after all the answers I began browsing the web to find out the reason why "threading is unpredictable"?

I read somewhere that the thread scheduling is dependent on the process scheduling by OS as process is actually made up of threads.

My questions are:

1) If my computer would arbitrarily have only one process running ie. Eclipse. Would the multithreading then give the expected results??

2) Is eclipse as a process got more threads running by default other that I coded.

Please help me I really want to know why I cant predict the output of my code??

Comment: What's Eclipse got to do with it? This is to do with the JVM. I would conjecture that you cannot feasibly have only one thread running unless you were to code in assembler against bare metal.

Comment: @BoristheSpider do you mean to say that there are always multiple threads running when the program is executing.

Comment: I mean to say that once you have an OS and on top of that a JVM and as you're running from Eclipse then on top of the Eclipse the CPU is dealing with hundreds if not thousands of threads.

Comment: Got that about the threads but do multiple processes also result in unexpected thread outcomes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, eclipse has other threads running. Also, a modern operating system always has other system processes running. Also, the operating system kernel itself has hidden threads running inside itself (at least, Linux does). Also, even if none of those things existed, the hardware itself can interrupt things with hardware interrupts, e.g. when the user presses a key on the keyboard.

There is a deterministic form of threading, and it is called co-operative multi-threading. No modern operating system uses it because it is not very good.

Comment: Sir after reading your answer i think Now i can continue with my study. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up Eclipse, threads and the JVM. If you write your app to use a single thread, eg just a main method, and you run into from within Eclipse then Eclipse will probably have lots of different threads and the JVM running your app can also have multiple threads (eg for garbage collection). But from the point of view of predictability you only need to worry about the thread for your app. You only need to worry about the various other threads when it comes to timing, eg you might get unpredictable GC pauses. The other threads will not affect the flow of your app.

If you start creating new threads in your app, then you need to start worrying about how the threads interact. It isn't that the flow is totally unpredictable, it is that you can't know the relative timing of the threads so you have to allow for that in your code.

eg suppose you have a function in a class that increments a class member variables and returns it:

```
int i = 0;
function foo() {
   ++i;
   // do some stuff
   return i;
}
```

If this called by two different threads then sometimes the function might return 1 and 2. Other times it might return 2 to both threads.

May be you need to write specific examples of multithreading where you don't understand what is happening so we can help you work through them.

Comment: his previous question was about thread interleavings being unpredictable, that's what he doesn't understand.